# Paging in grid view

Tags: asp.net

using paging in grid view but as i go through pagess i need to click on page links.. it should work on single click .. but it goes other page only after double click... any idea why..

Comment: post your markup code, but maybe you are using the ondoubleclick event preventing the default functionality of the LinkButtons in the GridView Pager.

Answer (score 1):

simple and working

```
protected void grd_receipt_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    grd_receipt.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    grd_receipt.DataBind();
}
```

simply call the databind after

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your code to call DataBind() on your grid is in it's own method.  You'll need to call it in two places.

1. On Page_load, if !IsPostBack, bind your grid.
2. When you're paging, set the new page index, then bind your grid.

This will eliminate your problem.